# Capturing the "antonym phrase" concept in Formal Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let's start with an example.

True is the antonym of False and Positive is the antonym of Negative. This can be represented in Logic as $\neg$False$(x)$ $\equiv$ True$(x)$ and $\neg$Negative$(x)$ $\equiv$ Positive$(x)$.

However the phrase "False Negative" has an antonym "True Negative", but not "False Positive" or "True Positive". Similarly the phrase "Good Person" has an antonym "Bad Person" but not "Bad Non-Person" or "Good Non-Person".

If we represent the concept of antonym phrase in logic it would become $\neg($False$(x)\land $Negative$(x))$  $\equiv$ True$(x)\land$Negative$(x)$, which is obviously not a valid logic sentence, as it does not stay consistent with the definition $\neg$Negative$(x)$ $\equiv$ Positive$(x)$.

I am wondering is there a way to represent the antonym phrase concept correctly using formal language. I think this would require two things: $(1)$ We need to somehow narrow down the domain of objects, and $(2)$ We need to somehow capture the order of the elements of the phrase, however I am not sure how to achieve these two requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $False(Negative(x))$
- $False(x)\land Negative(x)$

These are *not* the same.

---

When people say "false negative" in english, they refer to the first one.

The test can be negative, and the fact that it is positive or negative can be false. But the test itself cannot be false as you wrote in the second one.

Comment: Sorry I got a bit confused again about the $False(Negative(x))$ expression. Since $Negative(x)$ is either true or false, does this mean $False()$ predicate takes only boolean inputs (true and false) as its domain? Or does it take all the $x$ that satisfy $Negative(x)\equiv true$ as its domain? The latter is what I would want to have.

Comment: @cr001 In first order logic this thing you want to do doesn't exist. You would need a typing system for that and there's not a unique correct way to do that. But it would be natural in such a case to consider $False : Bool \rightarrow Bool$ indeed or even $False : Prop \rightarrow Prop$ for $Prop$ the Lindenbaum Heyting Algebra which is like a structure of generalized truth values. I'm not sure about the type of $Negative$ though. There are not many things which can be called negative.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.